Good, reliable, low-resistance electrical connections to an aluminum vacuum chamber
Vacuum chambers for physics experiments and scientific equipment are sometimes made of aluminum, though stainless steel and mu-metal chambers are used as well.
Aluminum forms a thin native oxide layer quickly, and this passive surface can have some advantages, but it's a serious impediment to making good, reliable, low-resistance electrical connections for purposes of electrical grounding for safety and for reducing various sources of electronic noise.
Just for example, it's hard to make a good Faraday cage from an aluminum box with vacuum ports and o-ring seals, or from aluminum foil for that matter.

How come a mobile phone signal is blocked by aluminium foil, but Wi-Fi gets through?

I have come up with one possible solution - Electroless nickel-phosphorus plating of at least selected areas (especially threaded holes) together with the right kind of screw might allow some terminal lugs to provide good, long-term connections, but whenever dissimilar metals are involved, especially in notoriously humid locations, I worry.

Laser welding is supposed to work great for mixing all sorts of metals.

@Abel thanks - I think that for thin sheets of dissimilar metal (say aluminum + copper) there are reports of it working, but a 100 kg block of aluminum makes for a huge heat sink with very high thermal conductivity. If you've seen an example of laser welding to big hunks of aluminum, please share it!

How thick a "thin native oxide layer" do you need? https://www.google.com/search?q=laser+weld+aluminum&tbm=vid just use a more powerful laser? Where do I get that? Same place you got that big hunk of aluminum.

Is there something wrong with mechanical connections like nuts and bolts and tapped holes, and two flat surfaces squashed together by fasteners ?  May need to lap the mating surfaces before assembly.   I have no idea if grease or similar would contaminate the chamber under low pressure, hence the tight flat fit suggested.

@Criggie Yes there is. Unlike other metals, Aluminum is super-reactive with oxygen. The native oxide that I mention in the question grows in seconds, and Al2O3 in other forms is known as a ceramic  (alumina) or crystal (sapphire). It's an excellent insulator. Other metals oxidize much more slowly after machining or cleaning; in hours or days, and very thin layers of those oxides are still partially conducting. But I suppose lapping in dry nitrogen followed by some serious mechanical squishing of a contact and sealing with something that doesn't emit oxygen or water is something to try.
